# How to create a vocabulary from a text file using bash?

Tags: bash

Given a text file, I want to output the words in the file with their frequencies. For example if the text file contained "I really really love burgers" the output should look like:

```
Burgers 1
I 1
Love 1
Really 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test file:

```
$ cat filename.txt 
I really really   love burgers
```

```bsh
cat filename.txt \
    | tr -s ' ' '\n' \
    | sort \
    | uniq -c \
    | sort -n -r \
    | awk '{ print $2 " " $1 }'
```

Output:

```
really 2
love 1
I 1
burgers 1
```

Lets breakdown all of that and explain each step. First, file is printed out by `cat` to `stdout`.

```
cat fileanme.txt
```

Then we pass output of `cat` to `tr` which will replace all spaces (`' '`) with newline (`'\n'`). The `-s` option squeeze spaces and makes `tr` to replace multiple spaces in to one `'\n'`. This produces one word per line even if in between the words we had multiple spaces.

```
tr -s ' ' '\n'
```

List of words we pass to `sort`. That will sort words alphabetically.

```
sort
```

Sorted list of words can be passed to `uniq` which will output unique list of words. `uniq` requires list to be sorted. `-c` flag outputs also counter before each word. Counter has couple of spaces reserved at the beginning of each line. This produces aligned words. Those spaces are removed in next step.

```
uniq -c
```

Now we can sort words by counter. `-n` causes `sort` to use first word in each line (counter) for numeric sorting. `-r` option reverse result (highest counter first).

```
sort -n -r
```

Finally with `awk`, using `print`, for all lines we swap words and counters. Extra spaces are cleared for free (`awk` uses spaces as fields delimiter, collapsing multiple spaces).

For each line we `print`:

- `$2` second field (word)
- `" "` - single space
- `$1` - counter

```
awk '{ print $2 " " $1 }'
```

Comment: It's easier with for example `awk`: `awk { print $2""$1 }`. Messing with regex to switch columns is not a good idea.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity thanks for good hint :) Already updated the answer.

Comment: thank you so much! Really appreciate this detailed answer.